# Networking understanding

Tags: networking, switch, subnet

Please be patient with me, I am new to networking and trying to understand. So, we have 3 computers with the same subnet mask, 255.255.255.0 and the same default gateway, 192.168.12.1 connected to a switch, and the first two have the same network address and the third one, a different network address, 192.168.12.113, 192.168.12.205, 192.168.112.97. Can these computers communicate with each other? If not, why not?

Comment: As long as they're in the same subnet, they can communicate. You can refer to this about how to determine whether two IP addresses belong to the same network segment https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-know-if-these-IP-addresses-are-in-the-same-network-How-can-I-ping-an-IP-with-a-different-subnet-mask

Answer (score 0):

The third will not be able to communicate with the first ones without the help of a router or additional configuration.

The reason is that the first two won't try to reach the third by broadcast because it is not in their subnet and the reverse applies as well.

Is there a particular reason why you configure different networks if you want them to communicate?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Because current subnet configuration allows only 192.168.12.*. If computer 192.168.112.97 have additional network interface with IP in 192.168.12.* subnet, then yes.
Or if change mask.

Answer (score 0):

Hosts within same subnet will communicate directly; that's what a subnet means. So I assume your question is about hosts that belong to *different* subnets, such as 192.168.12.205 and 192.168.112.97.

Technically, being on the same switch all of them are *capable* of communicating directly at Ethernet layer. If host A sends Ethernet frames with destination = host B, it will succeed. However, the IP layer *doesn't know* this, because the subnet mask tells it otherwise – so the hosts will not attempt direct communication and will need a router by default.

(In other words: Ethernet link *creates* the possibility of direct communication, IP configuration *informs* the host that such possibility exists.)

But it is possible to inform the IP stacks that direct communication is possible even to hosts within a different network address, by adding custom routes to each host's routing table. These would have to be "link" routes, specifying just the interface but not a gateway. (That's actually what the subnet mask does; it creates a link route.)

```
ip route add 192.168.112.0/24 dev eth0
```